# Recommend monitoring service with public REST API and SMS alerts?

Tags: monitoring, windows-service, uptime, pagerduty

I need to monitor my service for uptime. My service can only do push notifications of it's status. Meaning, I can report to some 3rd party that I'm alive and well, but it cannot act as a server by itself, so no pinging it.

Can you recommend existing web-service which support this mode of operation?
They should also support SMS alerts (or any other mobile phone notifications).

It would be cool for them to have a RESTful API so I can integrate my service with them.

I already took a look at Uptime Robot and PagerDuty but I cannot figure out if the support this mode of operation.

The service does not have to be free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try **Opsgenie-heartbeat**.

When a *heartbeat* is added to OpsGenie with an interval of 10 minutes, your system is expected to send http based heartbeat requests periodically, at least every 10 minutes. If a heartbeat request is not received for more than 10 minutes, OpsGenie will conclude that there is a problem between your system and OpsGenie and create an alert according to your settings. Opsgenie has standard SMS/Call/Push notification with support for tons of other notification channels like IRC, Hipchat etc.

You can add any number of heartbeats to work. You can configure the check intervals for each heartbeat separately up to once per minute.

[Heartbeat-monitoring](https://www.opsgenie.com/docs/miscellaneous/heartbeat-monitoring)

Answer (score 1):

And why not use a monitoring tool in your own environment? Long term is better to have in your network your monitoring checks as you can evade any firewall, so if something starts failing you can be sure that the problem is in your own network and not in some point in the way, and of course you could be able to monitor anything.

My recommendation for you is Pandora FMS, it include its own alert system and is very flexible. You can test the open source version and buy the enterprise if you need more features.

Hope this helps!